# Ubuntu Xenial upstart service not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I had an upstart service which worked fine in trusty by simply storing my conf at `/etc/init/test.conf`.  Now that I've upgraded to Xenial 16.04.2 LTS I'm having problems where the service isn't found.

Is a systemd script required now?  If you can still have a upstart with just the conf file, what must I do to resolve this?

Here's an example [from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it) which demonstrates the problem:

```
ubuntu@vagrant:~$ sudo ls -la /etc/init/test.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 126 Mar 24 10:54 /etc/init/test.conf
ubuntu@vagrant:~$ sudo cat /etc/init/test.conf 
description "Job that runs the foo daemon"
start on runlevel [2345]
exec echo Test Job ran at  `date` >> /var/log/testjob.log
ubuntu@vagrant:~$ sudo service test status
● test.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
ubuntu@vagrant:~$ sudo service test start
Failed to start test.service: Unit test.service not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xenial Xerus uses systemd instead of upstart. From [the release notes for Xenial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-s-new-in-ubuntu-16-04):

> Users of Ubuntu 15.10 or Debian Jessie may already be familiar with systemd, which is now the default init system for the majority of mainstream GNU/Linux distributions. On Ubuntu, systemd supplants Canonical's Upstart.
>
> If you make use of custom init scripts, or routinely configure long-running services, you will need to know the basics of systemd. For an overview, read [Systemd Essentials: Working with Services, Units, and the Journal](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal).

[This guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) may also be useful, from when Vivid came out.